# ¿Es posible crear multiples usuarios en la versión libre de OpenXava?

Tags: java, seguridad, openxava

El único usuario disponible in mi aplicación OpenXava es 'admin'. Sé que usando XavaPro tengo una gestión de usuarios y roles completa en mi aplicación OpenXava, pero XavaPro es un producto comercial.

¿Puedo añadir usuarios adicionales a mi aplicación OpenXava usando la edición de código abierto?

Answer (score 0):

Claro que puedes. Ve a la carpeta 'properties' dentro de tu proyecto. Allí encontrarás un archivo llamado naviox-users.properties, con este contenido:

```
# In plain OpenXava the users are added here in the form user=password
# If you want full management of users, roles and modules stored in database, 
#   get XavaPro from here: http://www.openxava.org/xavapro

admin=admin
```

Edítalo y añade todos los usuarios que quieras con pares usuario=contraseña, de esta manera:

```
# In plain OpenXava the users are added here in the form user=password
# If you want full management of users, roles and modules stored in database, 
#   get XavaPro from here: http://www.openxava.org/xavapro

admin=admin
juan=jfskd
antonia=fjlskd
bartolo=x2255
```

Has de reiniciar tu aplicación para que surta efecto.

Para aprender más sobre seguridad y gestión de usuarios con OpenXava mira: https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/security_es.html